# How do I allow a “flag” enum to be edited in the WinForm PropertyGrid?

Tags: .net, winforms, enums, propertygrid

The **WinForm** PropertyGrid copes well with a standard enum but does does have a built in editor for a flag enum.   Someone must have written one, I rather not reinvent the weel.

I am looking for an editor that puts a checkbox next to each member of the enum so the user can control the members that are included.   My enum looks like:

```
  [Flags]
  public enum AutoPricingCalendar
  {
        Sunday = 1,
        Monday = 2,
        Tuesday = 4,
        Wednesday = 8,
        Thursday = 16,
        Friday = 32,
        Saturday = 64,
   }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CodeProject: [A UITypeEditor for easy editing of flag enum properties in the property browser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/flagenumeditor.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I have just added this to may project and it worked first time.